# Proving that a non-negative additive set function is monotonous

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Let $\mu:\mathscr{C}\to\mathbb{R}=[-\infty,+\infty]$ is monotonous if $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ adnd for $E,F\in\mathscr{C}$, $E\subset F$ implies that $\mu(E)\leqslant\mu(F)$.
>   If $\mathscr{C}$ is a ring, prove that a non-negative additive set function is monotonous.

I have devised a proof that was wrong but I do not know the reason for that.

Let $A,B\in\mathscr{C}$ then as $\mathscr{C}$ is a ring then $A\cup B\in\mathscr{C}$. Taking $H=A\cup B$ then as the measure is non-negative $\mu(A)>0$ and $\mu(B)>0$.
Then it is obviously seen that:

$A\subset(A\cup B)=H$ and $\mu(A)\leqslant \mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)=mu(H)$

As $A,B$ are arbitrary sets of $\mathscr{C}$ we conclude $\mu$ is monotonous.

**Questions:**

Why is my proof wrong? Which are the alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ disjoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $E,F\in \mathscr{C}$ s.t. $E\subset F$,
$$
\mu(F)=\mu(E)+\mu(F\setminus E)\ge \mu(E).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is better. But I still do not understand why my answer is wrong. Could you explain me please?

Comment: You argue that $ \mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$. Are these sets disjoint?